# Can I add a status icon for thunderbolt ethernet to the menu bar? (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, internet, menu-bar

As the title suggests, I'm using a mac book pro with os x 10.9.2 and I connect to the network through the ethernet adapter thunderbolt.

Is there a way to get a reference icon in the menu bar, as is the case for the wifi?

I'd prefer not to use applications such as iStatsMenu or similar ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this from: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5598818

I quote

> Accordingly, I went into /System/Library/CoreServices/MenuExtras/ then double clicked on WWAN.menu for cable broadband. I think for DSL you'll need to click on PPPoE.menu.

Give it a try, otherwise you probably need third party apps like iStatsMenu

Comment: Thank you, if I add the PPPoE menu icon appears, but says it can not find the PPPoE settings, so you do not need to practically nothing. 

I think I will be forced to lean against third-party apps, even if they are all a bit 'suck!

Comment: What happens if you click the WWAN.menu item?

Comment: Nothing happens if i click WWAN.menu

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer but still for those landing here looking for a Ethernet connectivity status icon in menu bar, check this macOS app [Ethernet Status - The Missing LAN Status Bar Icon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ethernet-status-missing-lan/id1186187538?ls=1&mt=12). It shows ethernet interface, IP Address and if interface is active via changing menu bar icon. More [here](https://www.vikramrao.in/apps/ethernetstatus)

[image]

*PS: I am the developer of the app*